# Linear Layout - Inner Linear Layout doesn't get displayed

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Android 2.3.3

I am trying to create a header with the following idea in mind

```
              Expression
 S.NO         Result    

  1.          1+2+3
              6

  2.          2+3-4
              1
  .....
```

The data is populated from database into a listview. I am trying to create an XML for the header part of the listview. (SNO, Expression, Result).

Here is the XML I am using...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Count"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:text="Number"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.90"
        android:orientation="horizontal" > //If I change this to Vertical, 
                                           //the Output is not displayed

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Result"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:textSize = "22dp"
            android:text="Result"
            android:textColor="#316DA2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Expression"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:text="Expression"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If I change the Orientation of the second inner layout to Vertical, the texts are not being displayed. What is going wrong?

Also, I want the first layout to be 10% of the total available space (android:layout_weight="0.10") and the second layout to be 90% (android:layout_weight="0.90"). Then, the textviews in the second layout should span 50% of the available space in the second layout. Is there a way to create this, without nested weights?

Comment: Change parent linear layout orientation to vertical.

Comment: But that will make the Expression and Result come under the SNO. I want them to be side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it.. After a little twists and tweaks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Count"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:text="Number"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22dp" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textSize = "22dp"
            android:text="Result"
            android:textColor="#316DA2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Expression"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Expression"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```